# Find largest partition in Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new in Dynamo and I have a table that is partitioned by company id and receives news everyday related to the companies, so I just insert a new record for every news that I got using the respective company id. I would like to know if there is an easy way to know which company has the most news. I thought maybe by knowing the biggest partition, but I don't find info about this, do I have to query every company and count the items they return?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for you to know anything about the physical partitions in use by DDB.  I assume AWS Engineers can find out, but it's not something they are open about.

Unless your DDB data is more than 10GB, or you've configured(used) more than 3000RCU / 1000 WCU...it's highly probable that your data is in fact in a single physical partition....regardless of the number of partition key values in that data.

100 partition key values, doesn't translate into 100 physical partitions.